# missing 'expires_in' from Facebook oauth/access_token response

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get Facebook Long-lived User Access Token but I only get 'access_token' and 'token_type' from the response. As per the documentation, it should include the 'expires_in'.

The JSON response looks like this:

```
{"access_token":"xxxx","token_type":"bearer"}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using (minus secrets)?

Comment: Per the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/ it states that Long-Lived Tokens on the Page level do not have expiration dates.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm still having this problem.